# Powershell and one to many relationships / objects

Tags: xml, powershell, pipeline

I have created a function that reads a directory listing and then the files contents for CNC program names/numbers.  Each file have multiple program numbers which i have separated by "," and are passed on as a obj (see code below).  I want to export this to XML to upload to a database having each of the program names in a seperate entry.  Whats the best/easiest method to achieve this?

```
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FullFileName -Value $CNCProgFileName 
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ProgramName -Value $ProgramName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a custom object like you are doing is good. I suggest creating a property that is an array so you can associate the many things in the array to one object.

```
$myListOfStuff = @()
$myListOfStuff += "Stuff"
$myListOfStuff += "More stuff"

$obj = New-Object PsObject @{
    FullFileName = $CNCProgFileName
    ProgramName = $ProgramName
    ListOfStuff = $myListOfStuff
}
```

You can see your list of stuff with `Select-Object` with `-ExpandProperty` like so: `$obj | select -expand ListOfStuff`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce.  I'll give it ago tomorrow and provide feedback for other people.

Comment: The results still come out as a string, not a array.   I use the following to add program names to the variable "$ProgramName += $cncPrograms".  This however assigns the type of $cncprograms to ProgramName , i want just the value. Whats the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In PowreShell 2.0 you can use the `ConvertTo-Xml` cmdlet to produce XML from your objects.