# Powershell: Nested For Loops, returning 1 object from function

Tags: xml, loops, powershell, foreach, nested

I'm trying to read registry keys, properties and values and be able to call the function to create the an xml file and then elements inside the XML file.

My registry entries look something like:

```
HKCU\Software\TEX\library\...
...Key1
      Prop1, Value1
      Prop2, Value2
...Key2
      Prop1, Value1
      Prop2, Value2
      Prop3, Value3
...Key3
      Prop1, Value1
...Key4...etc
```

Each key contains 1 or more properties and their respective values.

The key(n) represents the xml filename (key1.xml, key2.xml, key3.xml etc...)
The properties and values represent elements inside the xml file.

The function is called inside a function that creates the xml file with its elements. So far I have it creating 3 files, but I end up with each file containing all properties and values from all keys. I need to work out a way for each xml file to contain only its respective properties and values. I believe the trick is in how this function returns its data. I am struggling getting it to return a single object that contains the accumulated data from both loops. Following a suggestion to another forum member's question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198622/powershell-and-one-to-many-relationships-objects), I have come up with the following:

```
function Get-RegValue ([string]$regPath){

       $regProp = (Get-ChildItem $regPath) 
       $scNameArray = @()
       $scRegValueArray = @()
       $scRegPropArray = @()
# Key loop
       foreach ($subKey in $regProp){
           $subKeyPath = $subKey.PSPath
           $prop = $subKey.Property
           $scName = $subkey.PSChildName
           $scNameArray += $scName
# Property & value loop           
          foreach($value in $prop){ # | Select-Object $scIndex.ToString() -Unique 
                $regValue = (Get-ItemProperty $subKeyPath).$value
                $scRegValueArray += $value
                $scRegPropArray += $regValue
           }
       }

 New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                        RegKey=$scNameArray
                        RegValue=$scRegPropArray
                        RegProperty=$scRegValueArray
                }
 }
```

This gives me one object with three arrays, one for each property. I can "expand" each object' property like so:

```
$obj = Get-RegValue -regPath $regPath

$obj.RegKey
$obj.RegProperty
$obj.RegValue
```

However, for the this function to work inside the function that creates the xml file, I think I need to be able to do something like this:

```
(Pseudo)
foreach($key in $obj.RegKey){
  $key.RegProperty 
  $key.RegValue
}
```

This doesn't work as $obj.RegKey only allows the return of "RegKey" object.

If this was a database, I'd need to create a "relationship" between the object' properties. Perhaps this is what I need to do. But how? Am I barking up the entirely wrong tree and there is a much easier way to achieve this?

Any help would be gratefully received.

Many thanks

W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is in Get-RegValue function. It returns an array of keys, property names and values, without association between keys and properties.

Yes, the trick is really in the way how to return the data. Instead of creating and maintaining the arrays by your self, you should just create objects and put them to the output and PowerShell will make the resulting array for you (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760.aspx).

You can use following code to create an array of objects (hashtables) which contains filenames (keys) and associated with them properties:

```
Function Get-SubItem([string]$RegistryPath)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $RegistryPath | % {
        $key = @{}
        $key.FileName = $_.PSChildName
        $key.Property = @{}
        foreach ($name in $_.Property) 
        {
            $key.Property.Add($name, $_.GetValue($name))
        };
        $key
    }
}

Get-SubItem -RegistryPath "HKCU:\Test" | % {
    Write-Host $_.FileName
    foreach ($entry in $_.Property.GetEnumerator()) 
    {
        Write-Host ("`t{0} - {1}" -f $entry.Key, $entry.Value)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. I didn't get an email to notify me of an answer. Thank you very much Levgen. Works a treat. I'm calling the Get-SubItem function from inside the Create-Shortcut function. Once the project is fully up and running, I'll document on my blog and update here.

Comment: Would be interesting to get a link on the blog to see how it will be working)). Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a `foreach` loop, you could use a `for` loop, thus creating a metarelationship between the items by using the array index:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt ($obj.regkey).count; $i++) {
    $obj.RegKey[$i]
    $obj.RegValue[$i]
    $obj.RegProperty[$i]
}
```

Comment: Vasili, Thanks for your reply. Levgen's solution is working for me, but I am intrigued by your solution and will certainly give it a try and feed back here. Thanks again.